# Get number before delimiter and -1 (previous month)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use this function: `=IF(((LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1))-1)<10,"0"&(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1))-1,IF((LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)-1)<=1,LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)+11,LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)-1))`

Which returns the good value when the number is less than "10": https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgOuO.png

But when the number is "1" the function should return "12" but it returns 00...: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1tTj.png

Basically, I want to subtract a month to each number.
ie: 09 = 08 OR 12 = 11 etc
But when it goes to 01 (January) I need to return 12 (for December). Any idea how to perform that or fix my function, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH(--LEFT(A1,7),-1),"mm")
```

Or, avoid the `TEXT()` function and just use a custom number format like `mm`.

Comment: Amazing. I didn't know this function. Thanks. Can it do the same for the year? When it's 01 (January) your function returns 12 (for December) but the year stays the new year of January. How can you return the previous year for December, please?

Comment: You can just use `mm-yyyy` as the formatting and see what happens @imbehindyou. If you only after the year just use `yyyy`

Comment: Works incredibly well. Thank you.